# Identifying the maximum value of each row in attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

I am trying to identify the maximum value from specific columns for each row in the attribute table of my shapefile.  Therefore I wrote the following script (as part of a bigger script):

```
layer = tmp_union ['OUTPUT']
einfields = [f.name() for f in layer.fields() if 'Ein' in f.name()] #List the fields
formula_max = max([f' "{einfield}"' for einfield in einfields])
# Feldrechner
alg_params = {
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_NAME': 'Maximum',
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
    'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
    'FORMULA': formula_max,
    'INPUT': layer,
    'NEW_FIELD': True,
    'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
}
tmp_max = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params)`
```

Now it seems like only the maximum value of all fields and all rows is identified, but I want to look at each row seperatly.

How can I revise my script to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Refactored')[0]
fields = layer.fields()
maxfieldindex = fields.lookupField('maximum') #5, add the field before executing the code below
fieldlist = [f.name() for f in fields if f.name().startswith('new')] #['new_field', 'new_field2', 'new_field3']

attributemap = {} #A dictionary to hold feature id, maxfieldindex and max value
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    maxval = max([f[fieldname] for fieldname in fieldlist])
    attributemap[f.id()] = {maxfieldindex:maxval}

#attributemap[1]
#{5: 9} #First feature's max value is 9, and it should be written to field with index 5

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap) #Update maximum field
```

[image]